# Multiple occurence of web notification

Tags: notifications, settimeout, onblur, cleartimeout

I want to show a web notification to the user if they left the page open for 10 seconds. I have already taken the notification permission.
**Problem** here is the **notification occurs multiple times** even if the user comes back to the page in less than 10 secs. Already use clearTimeout for flushing myVar value....but no luck.....any help!

```
var myVar;
window.onblur = function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function () {
        var notification = new Notification("XXX page is open in background ");
    }, 10000);
    clearTimeout(myVar);
};
```

want to make in such a way that only if user goes out of the page multiple times the notification will trigger everytime....but if he comes back to the page it will not appear..

Comment: I think you are asking two things: a) how to prevent multiple popups, and b) how to trigger the popup only after a user leaves and enters the page a few times. Please separate them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be due to testing. You must realize that window.onblur is triggered each time you leave the page. So if you leave, enter, leave, enter, leave, you will get 3 popups; each event runs independantly.

What you should do is call clearTimeout() in your window.onfocus event; don't forget to clear your myVar variable in both your popup handling code and your onfocus event (and test for it being null or not).

Comment: Hello jvo, i have tried to cleartimeout as well...but myVar value is not global as you can see in the code...so cant clear that in onFocus event....i am very new to this language...it would be very helpful if you can write some code..

Comment: The problem i am getting...is whenever i try to leave the page notification appears but when i open the tab again notification appears again.

Comment: You myVar is global as it is outside of the function (note: a more specific name would be useful, you never know which other library might use 'myVar'). The reason the popup appears when you open the tab again might be that the browser pauses popus when it is not active (imagine getting popups from other pages constantly, distracting you from your current work!).